# Using FS & NodeJS to list all files in a directory along with their character lengths

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to make a system where the number of characters are counted of all the files in the directory while still keeping the file name associated with it.

So for example if there are 10 text files in a folder named **votes**, and the text files are all named **[a random string of numbers].txt** (different for each file) with a different amount of characters in each of them, how would I gather all of the filenames and character counts of all of them? I know I would use **data.length()** to find the character count of one file, but is there a way I could do it with several?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Node-Cheat](https://github.com/zishon89us/node-cheat/blob/master/files/read_dir_files.js#L1) is available you can try it out by clicking [HERE](https://github.com/zishon89us/node-cheat/blob/master/files/read_dir_files.js#L1).

Possible option 1:

```
    var fs = require('fs'),
        async = require('async'),
        readMultipleFiles = require('read-multiple-files');

    var dirPath = 'votes/';

    fs.readdir(dirPath, function (err, filesPath) {
        if (err) throw err;
        filesPath = filesPath.map(function (filePath) {
            return dirPath + filePath;
        });
        async.map(filesPath, function (filePath, cb) {
            fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8', cb);
        }, function (err, results) {
            console.log(results);
        });
    });
```

Possible option 2:

```
    fs.readdir(dirPath, function (err, filesPath) {
        if (err) throw err;
        filesPath = filesPath.map(function (filePath) {
            return dirPath + filePath;
        });
        readMultipleFiles(filesPath, 'utf8', function (err, results) {
            if (err)
                throw err;
            console.log(results);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Great! But that only returns the content of the text files. Can I also retrieve the file names? (using the 1st option btw)

Comment: you can achieve your target by reading content or see if `fs.stat`is useful for you link: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_stats